# Reverse key value pairing in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need a way to reverse my key values pairing. Let me illustrate my requirements.

---

```
dict = {1: (a, b), 2: (c, d), 3: (e, f)}
```

I want the above to be converted to the following:

```
dict = {1: (e, f), 2: (c, d), 3: (a, b)}
```

Comment: but does it make any sense? from `{1: (a, b), 2: (c, d), 3: (e, f)}` and `{1: (a, b), 3: (e, f), 2: (c, d)}` you'll get different result in general

Comment: Is the order based on the displayed order or numerical key values? E.g. what would the result be if the original dict were `{2: (a, b), 1: (c, d), 3: (e, f)}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(old_dict, reversed(old_dict.values())))
```

Note, prior to Python 3.8, where dict_values objects are not reversible, you will need something like:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(old_dict, reversed(list(old_dict.values()))))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working perfectly. Could you elaborate on what zip does? I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed to do so.

Comment: @rishi here is what [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) does. Just to illustrate, look at `a = [1,2,3]; b = ['a','b','c']; print(list(zip(a, b)))`

Comment: Prior to Python 3.7 iteration order wasn't guaranteed, in which case the second approach would return arbitrary results (but the question probably wouldn't make a whole lot of sense in that case).

Answer (score 1):

## List instead of a dict

Assuming that your keys are always the integers from 1 to N, it seems that your dict should actually be a list. And whatever you use, you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name.

You would not lose any information with a list:

```
d = {1: ('a', 'b'), 3: ('e', 'f'), 2: ('c', 'd')}
l = [v for k, v in sorted(d.items())]
# [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

You also wouldn't lose any information by shifting the indices by -1.

## Getting the information back

- You have the sorted values directly inside `l`.
- If you need the keys, you can simply call:

```
range(len(l))
# range(0, 3)
```

- If you want the index `i`, you can call `l[i]`.

```
l[1] # Indices have been shifted. 2 is now 1
# ('c', 'd')
```

- If you want the original dict, you can call:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(l))
{0: ('a', 'b'), 1: ('c', 'd'), 2: ('e', 'f')}
>>> dict(enumerate(l, 1))
{1: ('a', 'b'), 2: ('c', 'd'), 3: ('e', 'f')}
```

- In order to get the reversed values, you can simply reverse the list:

```
>>> l[::-1]
[('e', 'f'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b')]
>>> l[::-1][0]
('e', 'f')
```

And, in order to answer your original question, if you *really* want to keep the proposed data format, you can call:

```
>>> dict(list(enumerate(l[::-1])))
{0: ('e', 'f'), 1: ('c', 'd'), 2: ('a', 'b')}
>>> dict(list(enumerate(l[::-1], 1)))
{1: ('e', 'f'), 2: ('c', 'd'), 3: ('a', 'b')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```py
dict_ = {1: ('a','b'), 2: ('c','d'), 3: ('e','f')}
values = [y for x, y in dict_.items()][::-1]
res = {}
for x, y in enumerate(dict_.items()):
    res[y[0]] = values[x]

print(res)
```

This is the output:

> {1: ('e', 'f'), 2: ('c', 'd'), 3: ('a', 'b')}

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish the desired outcome.

```
def rev_keys(d: dict) -> dict:
    '''Return dictionary structure with the 
        keys reasigned in opposite order'''
    old_keys = list(d.keys())
    new_keys = old_keys[::-1]
    nd = {}
    for ki in range(len(new_keys)):
        nd[new_keys[ki]]= d[old_keys[ki]]
    return nd
```

Given and input looking like:

```
dt = {'1': ('a','b'), '2': ('c','d'), '3': ('e','f')}

rev_keys(dt)
```

returns:

```
{'3': ('a', 'b'), '2': ('c', 'd'), '1': ('e', 'f')}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can zip the original dictionary's keys with the original dictionary's values, and since you want the values to be reversed, you can use the negative striding `[::-1]`.

Note that `dict.values()` cannot be subscripted, hence you will need to convert it into a list first:

```
dct = {1: ('a', 'b'), 2: ('c', 'd'), 3: ('e', 'f')}
dct = dict(zip(dct, list(dct.values())[::-1]))
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{1: ('e', 'f'), 2: ('c', 'd'), 3: ('a', 'b')}
```

Comment: Essentially the same answer as [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199832/6340496).

Comment: @S3DEV Actually, the eariler answer didn't have what I gave. It was then edited in.